# JSON Dropdown Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
    I am new to Ajax Call How to send dropdown selected values to my webmethod.
after selection of dropdown my charts are not rendering.. 
       My Ajax Call:
         $(document).ready(function(){ 

                    $.ajax({

                 type: "POST",
                url : "HazzardsDashBoards.aspx/GetReport",
                data: "{myparam1,myparam2}",                
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                complete: function (jqXHR) 
                {
                    var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    TrendChart(data);
               } ,
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error");
                }

          });
        });

        My Method:
        [WebMethod]
                public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReport()
                {
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                    try
                    {
                        string strQry = string.Empty;

                        strQry = " select YEAR(dt_ModifiedOn)[date],COUNT(*) [HazardCount] from tbl_name ";
                        strQry += " where int_PluginID = 4 and int_FeatureID=35  ";
                        strQry += " group by year(dt_ModifiedOn) ";

                        using (commonManager)
                        {
                            DataTable dt = commonManager.ExecuteDataTable(strQry);

                            Dictionary<string, object> row;
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                                {
                                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                                }
                                rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                    return rows;
                }
///
Trendchart script:
 function TrendChart(modelData)
  {
    var data = modelData.d;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
     .tickPadding(8)
     .ticks(5)
    .orient("bottom");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
   .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
    .orient("left");


var line = d3.svg.line()
     .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("#divTrend").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });
//alert(JSON.stringify(cities));

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);


//svg.append("text")
//     .attr("x",width/2)
//     .attr("y",height+margin.bottom)
//     .attr("text-anchor","middle")
//     .text("Year")


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("HeadCount");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
///
```

I need to send the dropdown details to the above method..
    After that i need to render chart based on the data.
Please check i had mentioned my trendchart script. and in pageload chart is not rendering i was struck there where it went wrong

Comment: Your code does not have any event being handled for the dropdown control (i.e  no selection change event). The answer #1 might helps you to get into some point. Give a try and post back if any help required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should work something like this. Since you say you have two dropdowns, I'll assume that you want the ajax call to run whether either of the two dropdowns' value is changed.

First, give both your dropdowns the same css class. In this example I used "myClass", but please use whatever is meaningful to you.

```
<select id="myDropdown1" class="myClass">...</select>
<select id="myDropdown2" class="myClass">...</select>
```

Then, we handle the change event of both dropdowns, identifying them by their shared css class. We pass the values of both dropdowns to the server:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".myClass").change(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "HazzardsDashBoards.aspx/GetReport",
    data: JSON.stringify({ val1: $("#myDropdown1").val(), val2: $("#myDropdown2").val() }),                
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        TrendChart(data.d); //usually webmethods return the actual response data within a sub-variable called d
       },
       error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
      }
  });
 });
});
```

And:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReport(string val1, string val2)
{
 //you haven't said how you want to use the value in your server-side method, so I'll leave that to you
}
```

Since you haven't shared what TrendChart looks like, or what sort of data it accepts, I'll have to assume that the webmethod is already returning the right data in the right format in order to render the chart.

Comment: I Need to send two dropdown values is it required to have two dropdown change function

Comment: @suryakoti ok I've edited it with an example using two dropdowns

Comment: Thats great but chart is not rendering in page load.

Comment: @suryakoti well you never mentioned that before. you've just edited the question to include that! you can't just keep adding more things to the question

Comment: @suryakoti if you would help with the second issue, please re-edit this question, accept my answer, and then ask a new question re the second thing. If you link to it from here I will take a look

Comment: @ADysonhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435185/bind-dropdownlist-using-web-method-by-ajax-call please check the link