# Bind Dropdownlist using web method by ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My Ajax call:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddl").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).find(":selected").val()
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : "HazzardsDashBoards.aspx/GetReport1",
            data: "JSON.stringify(id)",                
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
                complete: function (data) {

                    var data = JSON.stringify(data);

                },
                error :function()
                {
                  alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My webmethod:
        [web method]

```
  public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReport1(string id)
            {
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();             

                    string strQry = string.Empty;

                    strQry = " select YEAR(mwl.dt_ModifiedOn)[date],COUNT(*) [HazardCount] from tbl ";
                    strQry += " left outer join TRANS_HAZARD_HAZARD_DETAILS thzd on thzd.int_HAZARD_ID = mwl.str_ObjectID";
                    strQry += " where int_PluginID = 4 and int_FeatureID=35 ";
                    if (id != "")
                    {
                        if (id == "1")
                        {
                            strQry += " and  col= 'E'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strQry += " and  col= 'C'";
                        }
                    }                     

                    strQry += " group by year(mwl.dt_ModifiedOn) ";

                    using (commonManager)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = commonManager.ExecuteDataTable(strQry);

                        Dictionary<string, object> row;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                            }
                            rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }                   
                return rows;
            }
```

I am new to Ajax Call i send dropdown selected values to my webmethod. after selection of dropdown my charts are not rendering.. And after selection of dropdown values also my charts are not rendering .
It is showing  error alert.

Comment: 1. there's nothing anywhere in this code which would render any charts. 2. Your question says " after selection of dropdown my charts are not rendering.. And after selection of dropdown values also my charts are not rendering . It is showing error alert. " This sounds like the same thing twice. Is that what you intended to write? 3. In my previous answer to you I showed  you how to properly implement the "error" function in an ajax call, but you haven't used it here. If you do that you might get more useful info returned from the server.

Comment: @ADyson error which you wrote doesnt work in my application so i modifired .

Comment: doesn't work how exactly? It works for me in every ajax call I have ever written (and there are hundreds)

Comment: Error Alert is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Change this -> `data: "JSON.stringify(id)"` to `data : JSON.stringify({"clientID":id})` .

You need to send a JSON string.

Comment: unfortunately .net webmethods are screwy and you often have to do something like this: `JSON.stringify("id": id)`. But I agree the OP's code is definitely wrong either way. In a previous answer I showed him the correct way but he hasn't applied it here.

Comment: @ADyson i send the data format as you posted in previous one its not working.

Comment: @suryakoti in my previous example the webmethod had two parameters. In your new example it has one. So you need to adapt it appropriately. Either way, what you've given in the example above is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ADyson you had taken a class for that you had wrote change function it's not working so i prefer to take individual dropdown change function and passing parameter.